# Translate NSRangePointer from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm getting an error when translating some Objective-C code to Swift.

I'm using [`- attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:) of `NSAttributedString` and having an error concerning the `effectiveRange` parameter, which is an `NSRangePointer`.

Objective-C:

```
NSRange range;
id value = [self.textanalyze
                      attribute:attribute
                        atIndex:index
                 effectiveRange:&range]
```

Swift:

```
var range : NSRange?
var value : Any = self.textanalyze.attribute(attributes,
                      atIndex: index,
               effectiveRange: &range)
```

I got an error near `&range`.

Answer (score 13):

You need to unwrap the range.

Also, you need to initialize range. Otherwise, this will crash your program.

```
var range : NSRange? = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
self.textanalyze.attribute(attributes, atIndex: index, effectiveRange: &range!)
```

Or, if you don't want to unwrap your range (it might be nil), rewrite your function like this:

```
var range : NSRange?
doSomethingWithRangePointer(&range)

func doSomethingWithRangePointer(range : UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange?>) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

But you may not have needed to make your range an optional in the first place (think, does `range` ever need to be nil? If not, then it doesn't need to be optional.), in which case, just initializing range like this will work:

```
var range = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
```

Comment: That might work, but wouldn't it be easier to declare the range as a non-optional instead of unwrapping it in the function call?

Comment: @MartinR Sure would, but OP has implied range should be nil at some point. Otherwise, I don't think he would have left his range declared as an optional.

Comment: @MartinR Also, it's not that this might work. This will definitely work. See my example above.

Comment: I assume that OP declared it as an optional only due to a misunderstanding how the NSRangePointer parameter works.

Comment: @MartinR I added your input as the third option. However, OP might still need to use an optional NSRange, in which case, the second answer will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = sizeof(NSRange)
let objRangePtr:NSRangePointer = NSRangePointer.alloc(a) //alloc memory
objLayoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange(range, actualGlyphRange:objRangePtr)
let objRange = objRangePtr.move() //gain the value and dealloc()
```