# can not convert value of type 'NSRange!' to expected argument type 'NSRangePointer' Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am trying to find a character's CGRect from a Label. I found following [How do I locate the CGRect for a substring of text in a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417776/how-do-i-locate-the-cgrect-for-a-substring-of-text-in-a-uilabel/20633388#20633388) to be useful but the code is in Objective C. I tried into Swift language. Following in the Swift conversion of the Objective C code

```
var objLabel:UILabel = UILabel()

func getBoundingRectForCharacterRange(range:NSRange) -> CGRect {

    var objTextStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: objLabel.attributedText!)
    var objLayoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    objTextStorage.addLayoutManager(objLayoutManager)

    var objTextContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSizeMake(100,100))
    objTextContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    objLayoutManager.addTextContainer(objTextContainer)

    var objRange:NSRange!

    objLayoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange(range, actualGlyphRange: objRange)
    return objLayoutManager.boundingRectForGlyphRange(objRange, inTextContainer: objTextContainer)
}
```

I am facing following error saying

```
can not convert value of type 'NSRange!' to expected argument type 'NSRangePointer' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_NSRange>')
```

Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Also I tried following from one similar question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825506/1030951) but its also not working

```
var range : NSRange?
doSomethingWithRangePointer(&range)

func doSomethingWithRangePointer(range : UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange?>) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Kindly confirm that you are also working in latest Swift version as me. I use Swift 2.2 with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score -1):

Change the call to objLayoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange() as follows:

```
objLayoutManager.characterRangeForGlyphRange(range, 
  actualGlyphRange: &objRange)
```

Comment: In addtion, `objRange` needs to be an initialized NSRange, and not an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: When I try using &objRange, it suggested me to delete "&"