# Cannot convert value of type NSRange to expected argument type

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to attach few attributes to the NSAttributeString and keep getting the following error. [image: Screenshot]

```
 func strikeThroughStyle() {            
   let range = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
   // add styles to self
   self.attribute(self.string, atIndex: 0, effectiveRange: range)
 }
```

I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'NSRangePointer' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_NSRange>')

Comment: this might duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825301/translate-nsrangepointer-from-objective-c-to-swift

Answer (score 6):

[`attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:) is a *getter* method — it doesn't set/attach/add attributes, it reports to you what the attribute value is at a particular index in the string. As such, the `effectiveRange` parameter is an "out-pointer": you pass in a pointer to an `NSRange`, and the method fills in data at that pointer when it returns. In Swift (and within an `NSAttributedString` extension) you can call it like this:

```
var range = NSRange()
let value = self.attribute(self.string, atIndex: 0, effectiveRange: &range)
```

**However, that's not what you want.** You seem to be wanting to *set* an attribute on the string, not *get* the value of an existing attribute. For that, use `NSMutableAttributedString` and the [`addAttribute:value:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/addAttribute:value:range:) method, or (especially if you're applying attributes to an entire string) `NSAttributedString`'s [`init(string:attributes:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithString:attributes:) constructor.